# como puedo enviar parametros desde ajax a un controlador en codeigniter?

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

Quiero pasar parametros desde ajax a un controlador en codeigniter, lo he intentado asi:

```
$.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"controllers/Home.php",
        data: {
            'nombre': nombre,
            'correo': a,
            'asunto': asunto,
            'mensaje': mensaje
        },
        succes:function(data){
            alert("los datos fueron enviados con exito");

        },
        error:function(jqXHR,textStatus, errorThrow){
            console.log("error: " + errorThrow);
        } 
    });
```

pero entra en la excepción y me arroja el error que se plantea ahí.

Comment: Hola @Sammy y bienvenido,  por favor puedes colocar el error que te está dando para poderte ayudar mejor. Gracias

Comment: el error es: not found, lo lanza la excepción: error:function(jqXHR,textStatus, errorThrow){ console.log("error: " + errorThrow); }

Answer (score 0):

El problema que presentas es porque estas llamando el archivo (.php) por ende el error de 'not found', lo que deberias es llamar el procedimiento tal cual haces en la url ejemplo:

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"http://localhost:/index.php/NombreControlador/NombreMetodo", 
    data: {
        'nombre': nombre,
        'correo': a,
        'asunto': asunto,
        'mensaje': mensaje
    },
    succes:function(data){
        alert("los datos fueron enviados con exito");

    },
    error:function(jqXHR,textStatus, errorThrow){
        console.log("error: " + errorThrow);
    } 
});
```

En URL puede ser de esta otra forma `http://localhost:/NombreControlador/NombreMetodo`,depende de como tengas configurado el archivo .htaccess

Comment: correcto, ese era el problema, ya lo resolvi. muchas Gracias.